# Web API Help Pages always empty

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I've added Help pages Nuget package to create documentation for my Web API but it doesn't work for me, no API methods are shown.

I uncommented line :

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

I checked box XML documentation file and set path to `App_Data/XmlDocument.xml`

I don't use Glimpse as many solutions here write about it.

I even installed nuget package for help pages with authorization but it doesn't help

What is wrong with this? If I start empty project than it is working fine, but this API is too big to start all over again.

Comment: did you find a solution? Having same problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

In case you are using OWIN as middleware (just like me), you may be initializing a new `HttpConfiguration` inside it´s startup method. The problem is that the `HelpController` and the `HelpPageConfig` are using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`, which seems to be wrong. What helped me:

**Step 1: make the startup `HttpConfiguration` a static field**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.API.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        //new
        public static HttpConfiguration HttpCfg;
        //

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpCfg = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(HttpCfg);
            app.UseWebApi(HttpCfg);

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2: go to `HelpPageAreaRegistration` and edit the `RegisterArea` method like this**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "HelpPage_Default",
        "Help/{action}/{apiId}",
        new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

    //old
    //HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    //new
    HelpPageConfig.Register(Startup.HttpCfg);
}
```

**Step 3: go to `HelpController` and edit the standard constructor like this**

```
//old
//public HelpController() : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration){ }

//new
public HelpController() : this(Startup.HttpCfg){ }
```

I hope this helps and isn't too late ;)

Comment: @DoctorCox Did you keep the default `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in Global.ascx.cs?